# Mongoose: Sum all numbers of fields after $skip and $limit

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a query and I need to sum some values of the result of my query but I have  the [$skip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) and [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) to handle the pagination, but i need to calculate the sum of some fields ( the fields that i need to sum the values are `value`, `comissionValue`. and I need to count how many registers have in this query too).

**My query:**

```
...
Schedule.find(findTerm)
    .sort(
      sort
    )
    .skip(req.body.page * req.body.limit)
    .limit(Number(req.body.limit))
    .select(
      "value scheduleStart scheduleEnd comissionValue comissionType status customer.name service.name scheduleDate"
    )
    .exec((err, response) => {
      if (err) res.status(500).send({
        error: err,
        code: 0,
        message: langs[req.query.lang].somethingWentWrong
      });
...
```

I tried to iterate the array of objects `response` but i only get the early registers limited by `$skip` and `$limit`. I don't know how can i sum and count all the registers in this query.

Schedule (model)

```
 store: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  customer: {
    id: {
      type: String
    },
    name: {
      type: String
    },
    avatar: String,
    phone: {
      type: String
    },
    email: { type: String },
    doc: {
      type: String
    },
  },
  employee: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    avatar: String,
  },
  service: {
    id: {
      type: String
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    filters: [String]
  },
  info: {
    channel: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: 'app'
    },
    id: String,
    name: String
  },
  scheduleDate: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  scheduleStart: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  scheduleEnd: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  value: {
    type: Number
  },
  comissionType: {
    type: String,
    default: '$'
  },
  comissionValue: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  status: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
```

Comment: Can you show us the schema definition for `Schedule` model as well as the fields you need to sum?

Comment: @chridam i edit my post to you

Comment: Which fields do you want to sum on? Is it `value`, `commisionValue`?

Comment: Yes ( `value` and `comissionValue`), and i need to count the number of the registers before skip and limit too(because i use them for pagination)

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I got you correctly as I'm not familiar with the business logic above, what do you mean number of registers? Is it denoted by a field? Do you have like a sample and the expected output from that sample?

Comment: I need to sum  the fields `value` and `comissionValue` (i need a totalizer for each field). and i need to count how many registers i have in this query(`find`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use mongodb [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) for this type of query. It has all the operations you need like [Skip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/), [Limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/), [Count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/) and [Sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/)

Comment: but i can get a sum of the register before the skip and limit in that way?

Comment: Yes you can get a sum but you have to use $group stage of the aggregation framework. But with that you cannot use $skip and $limit so you also need to use $facet stage to run 2 aggregation pipelines. One to get paginated results and other to get the sum of the fields